# I am trying to set a Global Variable Class, but it is crashing. Anything I am missing?

Tags: java, android

Error Log:

> ```
>  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sellingbcom.myapplicationa/com.example.sellingbcom.myapplicationa.DisplayActivity}:
> ```
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast
>   to com.example.sellingbcom.myapplicationa.GlobalActivity
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> ```
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                                 at
> ```
>
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
>                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
>                                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> ```
>                                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
> ```
>
> cannot be cast to
>   com.example.sellingbcom.myapplicationa.GlobalActivity
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.example.sellingbcom.myapplicationa.DisplayActivity.onCreate(DisplayActivity.java:17)
>                                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5177)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
>
> ```
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143) 
>                                                                                                 at
> ```
>
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

I am trying to set a Global Variable Class, but it is crashing. I need to know What I am missing?

/* Global Class

```
 public  class  GlobalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int albumId;

    public int getAlbumId() {
        return albumId;
    }

    public void setAlbumId(int albumId) {
        this.albumId = albumId;
    }

  }
```

/* Manifest

```
   <activity android:name=".DisplayActivity"></activity> 
<activity  android:name=".GlobalActivity"></activity>
```

/* Activity Main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int x=10;
    final GlobalActivity globalAlbum = (GlobalActivity) getApplicationContext();
    globalAlbum.setAlbumId(x);
 }

 public void dispAct(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

 }
}
```

/* DisplayActivity

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);

    final GlobalActivity globalAlbum = (GlobalActivity) getApplicationContext();
    int x = globalAlbum.getAlbumId();

    TextView songLyric = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.disp);
    songLyric.setText(x);
 }
}
```

/* Activity XML

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.sellingbcom.myapplicationa.MainActivity">



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tgl_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:onClick="dispAct"
            android:text="PICK"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

/* Display XML

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/disp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe post the error log too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this way

1. Declare variable as public static
2. call it anywhere by using name of class

for example

```
public class Main12 extends AppCompatActivity {

public static int age;
}
```

call it by

```
Main12.age = 4;
```

you can even call it in other activities same app

Comment: can't make it work. Is this Main12 the MainActivity Java file? It is not working.

Comment: Got it... So it was that easy so along. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the base android.app.Application class and add member variables like

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private String someVariable;

public String getSomeVariable() {
    return someVariable;
}

public void setSomeVariable(String someVariable) {
    this.someVariable = someVariable;
}
```

now do this in manifest 
 must declare the class implementing android.app.Application (add the android:name=".MyApplication" attribute to the existing application tag)
like below

```
<application  android:name=".MyApplication" android:icon="@drawable/icon"  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Then in your activities you can get and set the as mentioned below

```
((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).setSomeVariable("foo");
String s = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getSomeVariable();
```

Comment: It is too long. Its on top.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
final GlobalActivity globalAlbum = (GlobalActivity) getApplicationContext();
```

is just wrong mainly because you cannot cast your application context to a specific `activity` class. If you really want a global class, you have to make sure one of its instances exist before you use it.

One of the options is to create a plain Java class with static fields. These will be available as soon as the app is initialised but, you'll have to be careful not to save anything that maybe holding a `context` variable in it as that'll be asking for memory leaks.

The second method is using `application` class. @hatib already posted it while I'm typing this :D. I was gonna say the same thing hereafter.